# when I try to insert value in list at the end it's give me None

Tags: python-3.x

``When I use insert in terminal it's work perfectly but it's not working. 
My full program is working but at the end 2nd line it's gives me None Result.

```
from random import shuffle
value=['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0']
get_string=input('Enter the string:- ')
try:
    position=int(input('Enter the Salt position:- '))
    salt_length=int(input('Enter the length of the salt:- '))
except ValueError:
    print ('Error:- Deserve a "intiger" number.')
    exit()
shuffle(value)
value=",".join(value)
value="".join(value.split(',',salt_length-1))
salt_value=value.split(',')[0]
print(salt_value)
if position >len(get_string):
    print('exit')
get_string=get_string.strip()
st=list(get_string)
print (st)
st=st.insert(position,salt_value)
print (st)
```

Comment: Also, instead of `value = ['a', 'b', … 'z']`, you can use `value = list(string.ascii_lowercase)`.

Comment: @grooveplex, I was just about to ask what the purpose of the `import string` was (it's never used in the code), but you just gave it a purpose ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `string.insert` is an in-place operation, which returns `None`

Just remove the `string=`

This part :

```
print (st)
st=st.insert(position,salt_value)
print (st)
```

Just becomes

```
print(st)
st.insert(position,salt_value)
print(st)
```

Which changes the code to :

```
from random import shuffle
value=['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0']
get_string=input('Enter the string:- ')
try:
    position=int(input('Enter the Salt position:- '))
    salt_length=int(input('Enter the length of the salt:- '))
except ValueError:
    print ('Error:- Deserve a "intiger" number.')
    exit()
shuffle(value)
value=",".join(value)
value="".join(value.split(',',salt_length-1))
salt_value=value.split(',')[0]
print(salt_value)
if position >len(get_string):
    print('exit')
get_string=get_string.strip()
st=list(get_string)
print (st)
st.insert(position,salt_value)
print (st)
```